# Android how to create a generic ripple effect?

Tags: android, optimization, enums, android-5.0-lollipop, ripple

There's some code that load the ripple when API version is 21 or more.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {           
    viewHolder.container.setForeground(context.getResources().getDrawable(type.rippleId));
}
```

But there, I load the drawable for a specific type. Here's my type:

```
public enum Type {

    GREEN(R.color.green_1, R.drawable.ripple_green_1),
    PINK(R.color.pink_1, R.drawable.ripple_pink_1),

    public int colorId, rippleId;

    private Type(int colorId, int rippleId) {
        this.colorId = colorId;
        this.rippleId = rippleId;
    }

}
```

what I'd like to do, is have a generic ripple effect, and load the color from the type. Because if tomorrow I have another type, I need to create another ripple drawable, with another color, it's not flexible.

I looked quickly, but there's no way to set a color. it's a set of drawables or something.

I was wondering if there's clean way to create a drawable (from code or XML), and set a color.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android how to create ripple effect in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817185/android-how-to-create-ripple-effect-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

check this [ripple effect library](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) and try to implement that example in your app.

use [this](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/andexert/library/RippleView.java) class for your purpose.